# Weightage and value calculation

Tags: sql

I have the below scenario where I need to calculate the score value for the field value provided in the below table

```
--------------------------------------------
DataField                      FieldValue
--------------------------------------------
DataField1                     21
DataField2                     59
DataField3                     72
DataField4                     521
```

And we have a reference table which looks something like this

```
--------------------------------------------
ValueFrom        ValueTo        AssignedValue
--------------------------------------------
0                20             1        
21               40             1        
41               60             1        
61               360            12
361              999            1 --(1 point for every 15 after 360)
```

and the intended result should look something like this

```
--------------------------------------------
DataField      FieldValue      ScoreValue
--------------------------------------------
DataField1     21              2  (1+1)
DataField2     59              3  (1+1+1)
DataField3     72              15 (1+1+1+12)
DataField4     521             23 (15+11)--(161 = 150+11 i.e. 10+1)
```

I hope the question is clear enough ? Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: I am expecting millions of data to be handled in this query hence I feel correlated sub query can have impact on my performance, right now I am trying with right outer join to get all the data moreover I have one more scenario which I just updated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are calculating scorevalue ?

Comment: Ok, for till DataField3 I think it is pretty straightforward you add up the assigned value till the "FieldValue" is less than "ValueTo" it gets tricky only when the "FieldValue" is greater than the last "ValueFrom" for that we need to assign "1" ScoreValue for every 15 from 361, so the excess value for this example of 521 the value would be 161(521-360), here we have 150 +11 that is 10 fifteens and a eleven so if we assign one ScoreValue for each 15 then it has 10 + 1 score. I hope that is clear !!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table names are `T1` and `T2` only thing i can think of is:

```
SELECT 
    T1.DataField as DataField, 
    T1.FieldValue as FieldValue, 
    (SELECT SUM(T2.AssignedValue) FROM T2 WHERE T2.ValueFrom < T1.FieldValue) as ScoreValue
FROM
 T1
```

if it is not that, then provide more data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query to `SUM`:

```
select DataField,
       FieldValue,
       (select sum(AssignedValue) from table2 t2
        where t2.ValueFrom < t1.FieldValue) as ScoreValue
from table1 t1
```

Or do a `JOIN`, with `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.DataField,
       t1.FieldValue,
       SUM(t2.AssignedValue) as ScoreValue
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.FieldValue > t2.ValueFrom
group by t1.DataField,
         t1.FieldValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like the following

```
select DateField, FieldValue, sum(assignedValue) as ScoreValue
from (
        select DateField, FieldValue, AssignedValue
          from T1 
         inner join T2 on T2.ValueFrom <= T1.FieldValue
         --
         union all
         --
         select DateField, FieldValue, (FieldValue - 375)/15 as AssignedValue 
          from T1
         where FieldValue > 375  
         -- Values 361 - 375 will pick up the first point per 15 in the first select
     ) inlineTable
group by DateField, FieldValue
```

**Just to explain my thinking here:** The first select in the union will join the first table to every row where the ValueFrom is less than or equal toFieldValue.

Values over 360 will only get one point so we need something to fix this up for records that should get extra points for being 15 or more higher than 360. This is where the second select comes in - and why it only applies to FieldValues greater than 375. To calculate the extra points required we find the difference between FieldValue and 375 and then divide this by 15 - assuming both values are defined as `int` in the database the result shouldn't go into decimals and will return an int.

Finally we sum all the records grouped by DateField and FieldValue.